# replacing java script files dynamically with button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

The below code has 3 buttons. While the first two buttons use **draw.js**, the 3rd button uses **shapes.js**. Both javascripts have an `onclick` event handler, so I cannot use both scripts at same time.

Is there a way I can dynamically replace javascript in button click? Like when I press add polygon or add line only **draw.js** works and when I press add doors **shapes.js** works?

I tried following: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss2.shtml but didn't understand anything and made a mess out of my code. Similarly, as you can guess by the code, I am drawing on canvas so I don't want to lose anything on my canvas that is already there when I change my script.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="shapes.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="draw.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div id="board">
        <canvas id="canvas1" width="300" height="300" style="border: 1px solid black;">  </canvas>
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="Add polygon" class="draw" data-type="poly">
        <input type="button" value="Add line" class="draw" data-type="line">
        <input type="button" value="Add door" >
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"...both javascrips have onclick event handler so i cannot use both scripts at same time..."* What makes you think that? Perhaps if you *showed* the relevant bit (there is no `onclick` event handler in what you've posted), we could help you understand how to use it correctly.

Comment: once script is loaded, it is loaded, no way to remove it unless you overwrite it

Comment: Are not your event handlers linked to specific buttons. If you gave each button a unique id the you could use document.getElementById('button0').addEventListener to call the actual function you wanted to fire for the onclick event for that element or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

you can use  HeadJs library .

HeadJS is a JavaScript file and module loader, a small library for Responsive Design, Feature Detections & Resource Loading

HeadJs is great and useful, try it.

Need to quickly load a JS or CSS file

// Load up some JS

head.load("jQuery.js", function() {

```
// Call a function when done
console.log("Done loading jQuery");
```

});

// Load up some CSS

head.load("bootstrap.css");

Answer (score 0):

You can use RequireJS library for it( http://requirejs.org/ ). RequireJS is a JavaScript file and module loader. It is optimized for in-browser use, but it can be used in other JavaScript environments.

Like this, you can add any JS by RequireJS:

```
<script data-main="shapes.js" src="js/require.js"></script>
```